# -2146232576 Error MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

I am running MSBuild on our new build server for an ASP.Net MVC 5 C# project using.Net v4.5 but get the following exception, I can't find any resources on it though.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Transform\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AspNetCompileMerge.targets(516, 5):
error MSB6006: "aspnet_merge.exe" exited with code -2146232576
```

Turning on verbosity for MSBuild I get the following.

```
[MyApp.csproj.teamcity] AspNetMerge
[22:19:22][AspNetMerge] Using "AspNetMerge" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Transform\..\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll".
[22:19:22][AspNetMerge] AspNetMerge
[22:19:22][AspNetMerge] Running aspnet_merge.exe.
[22:19:22][AspNetMerge] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\aspnet_merge.exe C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\9cfa4fd6593d694d\MyApp\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir -o MyApp.Merged -copyattrs obj\Release\AssemblyInfo\AssemblyInfo.dll -a  
[22:19:22][AspNetMerge] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Transform\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AspNetCompileMerge.targets(516, 5): error MSB6006: "aspnet_merge.exe" exited with code -2146232576.
```

---

After trawling through various articles, sites and forums I still haven't found a definitive answer. However it led me to install .Net Framework Version 3.5 on our build server (which includes .Net version 2.0) and it has altered the exception to a more general asp_net merge one. However I don't really get sufficient information to work out what is wrong, I still feel this is linked to my original problem.

```
[MyProject.csproj.teamcity] AspNetMerge (4s)
[18:46:36][AspNetMerge] Using "AspNetMerge" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Transform\..\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll".
[18:46:36][AspNetMerge] AspNetMerge (4s)
[18:46:36][AspNetMerge] Running aspnet_merge.exe.
[18:46:36][AspNetMerge] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\aspnet_merge.exe C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\9cfa4fd6593d694d\MyProject\obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\TempBuildDir -o MyProject.Merged -copyattrs obj\Release\AssemblyInfo\AssemblyInfo.dll -a  
[18:46:36][AspNetMerge] Utility to merge precompiled ASP.NET assemblies. Version 3.5.30729.
[18:46:36][AspNetMerge] Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.
[18:46:36][AspNetMerge] 
[18:46:40][AspNetMerge] aspnet_merge error occurred: An error occurred when merging assemblies: Unresolved assembly reference not allowed: System.Web.
[18:46:40][AspNetMerge] The command exited with code 1.
```

Comment: The info above is very little to go on.  Add verbosity to your msbuild.exe call.       msbuild.exe MySolution.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /verbosity:detailed

Comment: Turning on verbosity produced the following output, there is much more going on before these lines, but this is the section that exhibits the error. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you checked similar posts? http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2006/07/31/86754.aspx

Comment: I added more project info. Sadly that article doesn't help. I did google around prior to posting on SO and found that article. The error message is different and they are using .Net v2.0 along with an older MSBuild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out after trial and error (a lot of it) that AspNetMerge path was incorrect.

The file at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Transform\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.AspNetCompileMerge.targets
```

Has a section which was pointing to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\bin\
```

I have since changed the .targets section to look like:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AspnetMergeName>aspnet_merge.exe</AspnetMergeName>
  <AspnetMergePath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\</AspnetMergePath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Everything builds as planned now.

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition to what has been already answered.

Our Case: We installed 4.5.1 sdk on our build server (Ccnet) which was already building v4.0 solutions and stopped after the sdk installation.

Solution : Changed the path of  in "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v10.0\Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets" to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64"

Hope it helps.